# Can we implement Scrum with activeCollab?

Tags: scrum, agile, pm-software

We are currently using activeCollab for our agile software development team. We are thinking of switching over to Scrum. Is it worthwhile to do so? I think the team may find it a bit difficult to use Scrum. And is it possible to implement the Scrum process using activeCollab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We are currently using active collab for our agile software development team. We are thinking of switching over to scrum. Is it worthwhile to do so?

Try it, and find out for yourself. You are asking a subjective question here. Only your own organisation, through trial and error, can provide the definitive answer.

> I think the team may find it a bit difficult to use scrum

Then you need to factor training and resistance to change into any trials of scrum within your organisation.

> And is it possible to implement Scrum process using active collab?

A cursory google of "active collab agile" would suggest it may be possible.